# Keyboard events not getting called on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have some logic to handle the keyboard events:

```
componentWillMount() {

  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    this.keyboardWillShowSub = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardWillShow',
      this.keyboardShow
    );
    this.keyboardWillHideSub = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardWillHide',
      this.keyboardHide
    );
  } else {
    this.keyboardDidShowSub = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this.keyboardShow,
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideSub = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      this.keyboardHide
    );
  }
}
```

On ios it works perfectly, but on android the function never get called.

Indeed, i must use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`